# Is the following use of "as sure as in ..." correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, colloquial-language

> As sure as in "this place surely stinks."

Is the construction and usage correct? I'm having doubts since the "example" is using a modified version of "sure." But maybe that's okay?

Comment: I have no idea what the phrase is supposed to convey. It looks like the conflation of two very different constructions, "as _adjective_ as something" and "'word' as in _phrase including 'word'_".

Comment: @ColinFine I see. So it should be: "sure" as in this place "sure" stinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions beginning with the phrase "As sure as..." are commonly used in English. The expression usually comes in three parts.

> 1. As sure as...  (Sometimes reduced to "Sure as...")
> 2. an expression that is usually regarded (at least by the speaker) as being true.  This can sometimes be comical, or religious, or profane or just some extemporaneous thing that the speaker felt was appropriate.
> 3. Followed by a statement that the speaker wants the listener to take seriously (or semi-seriously).

So you can get expressions starting with:

> As sure as...:

Plus a middle expression such as:

> ...God made little green apples,...
>
> ...pigs are made of bacon,...
>
> ...hell,...
>
> ...I am standing in front of you,...
>
> ...death and taxes,...

And finally an ending expression such as:

> ...I'm going to hurt you if you don't shut up.
>
> ...I'm going to marry that girl before next summer.
>
> ...it's going to rain for the weekend.
>
> ...I had nothing to do with it.

This form of expression is more commonly heard in country areas, but it is used in urban locations as well.  The overall affect of the expression is to say, "As sure as "A" is true then "B" is also true". The form of words used in "A" can be formulaic, but they are just as likely to be made up on the spot. It can be regarded as a form of oath attesting to the truth of something.

Sometimes, especially if you have been asked a question, your response can leave  "B" out of the oath. e.e.

> Are you sure that you didn't take my wallet?
>
> As sure as I am that there probably wasn't anything in it worth stealing.

This appears to have happened in the sentence that you quoted, as it only contains two parts of the expression, leaving out part "B", which would have been a (usually negative) restatement of the question that was asked. Apparently, they are in a smelly location, so in part "A" of the response the speaker draws on an obvious truth, "this place surely stinks". I don't know why this is placed within quotation marks, unless somebody previously made that statement in the speakers hearing.

Comment: This is such a great answer. Too bad it got buried.